# Specifying dynamic file upload location

Tags: python, django, django-models

So, I just started learning Django and I wanted to make an app. It's a simple app and I've just initialized my admin view and then I have a model named "Book". It's just like information about a book. The user can enter book name, author, description and upload a book cover image.

I got this working without a hiccup. But, currently, the image is being saved in the "/media" folder, because that's what I specified in the MEDIA_ROOT of the settings file (which is totally fine). Now, what I want is that instead of this in my models.py, it gets saved to it's own directory. For example :

Book Name : If god was a banker

I want the cover image to be saved in "/media/albums/If God Was A Banker".

How can I do this? I looked into the "upload_to" attribute of the "FileField". So, I tried something like this :

```
book_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, allow_blank=False,trim_whitespace=True)
comic_image = models.FileField(upload_to='%s/' % book_name)
```

and of course this didn't work, as `book_name` didn't return the str type (I knew it'll go wrong though). So, how can I get this to work? anything I'm missing or anything that I could do to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upload_to` argument can be callable.
So you can define function like this:

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return '{}/{}'.format(instance.book_name, filename)
```

and then use this function in model:

```
comic_image = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location)
```

Comment: it was so simple. Damn. Thank you so much! So, this `instance` is what? The instance of current class?

Comment: @Xonshiz You are welcome! yes, instance of current model class.

Comment: Oh, I see. Great! (Y)